# How do I use look-ahead in regex to match on no character?

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript, regex-lookarounds

I've got a set of regex's within a function that are working rather well for me, but I've encountered a new pattern where they fail.  This function fails when there are no more characters in the string.  For example my function matches and replaces text in the following:
"`1 m is equivalent to...`" becomes "`1 meter is equivalent to...`"  However, it fails on: 
"`There are 100 cm in 1 m`"

I'm using AS3, which I believe has a regex engine nearly equivalent to JavaScript's.  The current pattern is:

```
[0-9]+ m(?= )|[0-9]+m(?= )
```

I loop through a list of patterns and replacement strings, so it was easy to add another pattern to the list.  I tried:

```
[0-9]+ m(?=)|[0-9]+m(?=)
```

And:

```
[0-9]+ m(?='')|[0-9]+m(?='')
```

And both failed.  I'm missing a fundamental tidbit of knowledge.  I believe I need to know how to say, "look-ahead and match when there are no other characters in the line"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify your expression by looking for a word boundary (`\b`); something like this:

```
var regex = /(\d+)\s*m\b/;
regex.exec('1 m is equivalent to...'); // => ["1 m", "1"]
regex.exec('There are 100 cm in 1 m'); // => ["1 m", "1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

'No other characters in the line' is equivalent to 'at the end of the line' so just use the `$` metacharacter

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a word boundry which is represented by the sequence `\b`. You could use the expression `/\d+\s*m\b/`

```
\d+  - one or more digits
\s*  - any number of spaces
m    - a literal 'm'
\b   - a word boundry
```

Comment: To align with the patterns in the question, the `\s` subpattern should be optional, *i.e.*, `\s?`  or `\s*`.